# tcp connection never establishes

Tags: tcp

to undestand how tcp/ip works i'we wrote my implementation of the tcp/ip stack, i can successfully get IP address from DHCP server, can ping, but can't get TCP to work.i'm trying to connect to port 80 on microcontroller with MII PHY using chrome browser on win8. my log can be downloaded by link http://prefiles.com/rbmiresq8x51/my.pcap

for my knowledge of how TCP packet should look... tcp SYN/ACK responce is correct, wireshark colored it as green,but anyway i think the issue appearing when i'm composing tcp SYN/ACK packet, can anybody check whats wrong? the packet looks OK, all field correctly filled.

littlebit offtopic - browser always sends packets with corrupted checksum is it normal, trouble with win8 or chrome browser?

Comment: The last issue is because your PC offloads checksum generation to the NIC, so it's invalid when Wireshark sees it.

Comment: What issue? You haven't actually stated what's going wrong here.

Comment: EJP, The issue is - client(chrome browser) sends SYN, i'm(stm32 MCU) answering with SYN/ACK,but from client ACK isn't sent, wireshark shows SYN/ACK as correct and related to SYN(depending on ACK and SEQ fields), so ACK must be sent to approve connection from client side. it's like wireshark sees my SYN/ACK, but chrome not and retransmits SYN again. so my question why?

Comment: I can't see your pcap (link unavailable) but did you remember to increment the sender's sequence number in the SYN-ACK? The SYN costs the sender one sequence number. I seem to remember this one tripped me up when I wrote a [full TCP/IP stack](http://andybrown.me.uk/2013/07/14/stm32plusnet/) for the STM32 in C++ a few years ago.